# Loading external JavaScript files over HTTP on website that uses SSL

Tags: javascript, ssl

What are potential drawbacks of loading an external widget over HTTP when my website is accessible over HTTPS ?

```
<!-- https://www.example.com -->
<script src="http://www.external-source.com/widget.js"></script>
```

Are any warnings going to be displayed to the user? Any way to suppress them? Will this script be loaded in all times?

EDIT:

What happens when we load an external JS over HTTPS, but with non-commercial certificate? Will the warnings be shown?

Comment: It depends on the Browser settings. If you're really concerned about warnings being shown to the user, why not host the file yourself?

Comment: Can you tell me more? I cannot host it on my server because this file is dynamically generated.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content for more info on the problem. As for the solution: i'd use Reverse Proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading a script with plain (insecure) http inside a secure (https) site completely defeats the security of the site. Therefore most modern browsers will simply refuse to load the script without any warnings and without giving the user a way to enforce the loading.